# React in tsx delete state value onClick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tsx

I want to filter categories and need to see them if i click on the category. I also need to remove them if i click on them again. I saved all my active categories in a state and want to delete them after i click on them again, now is my question how do i do that the smartest way?
State:

```
const [activeCategories, setActiveCategories] = useState<string[]>([]);

function handleClick(catId: string) {
    setActiveCategories([...activeCategories, catId]);
}
```

With ActiveCategories ill get the active Id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the handleClick function to check if catId exists. Remove it if it does and add it if it doesn't exist in state:

```
function handleClick(catId: string) {
    if(activeCategories.findIndex(id => catId === id) >= 0){
        const updateState = activeCategories.filter(id => id !== catId)
        setActiveCategories(updateState);
    } else {
        setActiveCategories([...activeCategories, catId]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now if i log activeCategories there is just an empty array

Comment: Where are you placing your log statement inside the handleClick function?

Comment: it worked for me now, i placed the log in the end of the handleclick function